# Where to save untitled sftp configuration file for Sublime text?

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimetext3, sftp

I don't understand how to setup ftp on Sublime.
I downloaded [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/) and then I installed [Sublime sftp](http://wbond.net/sublime_packages/sftp/installation).
So now I need to enter my credentials, which I see when I go to File, SFTP, Setup Server, BUT:

What do I do once I change the untitled document? Where do I save it so that sublime uses it?

Answer (score 3):

The file should automatically be saved in the correct place once you hit Save. This directory is `Packages/User`, where `Packages` is the directory opened in your operating system's file manager (Windows Explorer, Finder, Nautilus, etc.) when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**. This directory varies by operating system and installation type (standard vs. portable), but for standard installs the locations generally are as follows (replace the `3` with `2` for Sublime Text 2):

**Linux:**

```
~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages/User
```

**Windows:**

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages\User
```

**Mac OS X:**

```
~/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User
```

For OS X and Linux, `~` indicates your home directory (`/Users/username` and `/home/username`, respectively).

Comment: It says "save file as type", but it doesn't give me a file extension. Q: What extension should I give this file?